# Reading a specific .txt file?

Tags: java, eclipse, hashtable, text-files

I have a special .txt file to read from Java, and here's a part of it:

```
absolute                            mutlak(IBM)(MS)
absolute address                    mutlak adres(IBM)
absolute device                     mutlak aygıt(IBM)
absolute positioned object          mutlak konumlu nesne(MS)
absolute positioned paragraph       mutlak konumlu paragraf(MS)
absolute positioning                mutlak konumlama(IBM)
absolute priority                   mutlak öncelik(IBM)
Absolute reference                  Mutlak referans(MS)
abstract                            soyut(IBM)(MS)
```

first column is **original** and the second column is the **description**. Now I have to read **original** and **description** seperately and store in a hashtable. How would I do that?

Comment: How do you define which is which? Are they seperated by `tab`s? is it guaranteed? can `tab` appear in anywhere else in the text?

Comment: the space between columns is 2 tab space. And after the second column (or ")" character) line ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file line by line. For each line, find the index of the `"  "` substring (two spaces). Extract everything before the index and everything after. Trim both parts.

If the separator is in fact a series of tabs, then use the same algorithm with `"\t"` instead of `"  "`.

Answer (score 0):

It's posible that you have a *layout* description of this file, whith lengths and positions in the lines.

```
start  end    description
0       10    original
11      50    description
```

Read line by line, then in each line, substring by **start** position and **end** position.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression/Pattern as the argument to `String.split()`. Something like `\\s{2,}` will split the string at any consequtive sequence (more than 1) of white space characters (space, tab, etc.).